# Get all SSH Keys of developers of a GitLab project via API

Tags: bash, ssh, gitlab

We have a self hosted GitLab CE instance.

How can we get all public SSH Keys of all developers of a project from another server via API?

We can get the users of a project an then fetch the keys for each single user, but is there a more efficient way?

I could not find out if GitLab CE supports GraphQl, it seems it does not?

*Update* GraphQL is enabled on CE:

```
{
    project (fullPath: "foo/bar/myproject"){
    name
    description
    archived
            projectMembers {
      nodes {
        user {
          username
          
        }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But there seems to be now field for fetching the SSH public keys the same time in the [API doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/graphql/reference/#user).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for "[Fast lookup of authorized SSH keys in the database](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup.html) " does mention:

> By default, GitLab manages an `authorized_keys` file, which contains all the public SSH keys for users allowed to access GitLab

So check your GitLab server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` first.

Comment: Thanks. But the idea is to fetch the list from another server via API or HTTP.

Comment: @Alex I agree, but I don't know of an API for that: you can fetch the users id, and cross reference them from the list of public keys found in the authorized_keys file.